# У меня проблема с подключением шрифта через @font-face. В шрифте присутствуют, но не подключаются русские буквы

Tags: css, шрифты

Имеется сайт, на котором подключён шрифт OpenSansRegular. 
Я беру из этого проекта файлы шрифта и подключаю его на другой сайт.
Всё ок, но появляется проблема: этим шрифтом отображаются только НЕ русские символы. А русские как будто не видят этот шрифт и для них идёт следующий по списку. Но шрифт тот же самый, что и в другом проекте, и там он отображается правильно. Я смотрел шрифт просмотрщиком, там ЕСТЬ русские буквы. И импортируется шрифт успешно, в консоли браузера нет ошибок.
В консоли шрифт выводится верно: font-family:OpenSansRegular;
Я не понимаю, как это вообще? Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём проблема?

Подключение:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: OpenSansRegular;
  src: url('./components/fonts/OpenSansRegular.eot');
  src: url('./components/fonts/OpenSansRegular.woff2') format('woff2'),
  url('./components/fonts/OpenSansRegular.woff') format('woff'),
  url('./components/fonts/OpenSansRegular.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('./components/fonts/OpenSansRegular.svg#OpenSans-Regular') format('svg'),
  url('./components/fonts/OpenSansRegular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Использование:

```
body {
  font-family: OpenSansRegular, "Arial Black";
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Пример вывода шрифта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: похоже шрифт "паленый" . Почему бы не использовать https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans?selection.family=Open+Sans где наверняка оригинальный шрифт используется! Можно ссылкой вставить, можно скачать!

Comment: Попробую. Задача стояла, как "сделать 1 в 1 дизайн", поэтому и скопировал шрифт, вёрстку, css и вообще всё. Кстати, если шрифт кривой, то почему на старом-то сайте он нормально показывается? В чём магия?

Comment: @ostet Дропните, пожалуйста, куда-нибудь файлы шрифтов. Погоняю у себя.

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/yZE6Iwo4mzQw8Q

Comment: В итоге скачал шрифт с гугла по ссылке выше, с ним проблем нет. И весит шрифт в три раза больше. Видно, всё же в старом что-то было вырезано.